# After Insert Trigger using the values from the INSERT

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO LOAN (MemberSSN, VolumeID, LoanDate) 
OUTPUT inserted.MemberSSN, inserted.VolumeID, inserted.LoanDate 
VALUES ('488-40-', 2, GETUTCDATE())
```

I want a trigger that, upon insertion in the `LOAN` table, the following query is executed - an INSERT into the `VOLUME_VOLUME_STATUS` table:

```
INSERT INTO VOLUME_VOLUME_STATUS (VolumeID, StatusID, DateCreated) 
VALUES (>>previouslyInsertedVolumeID<<, 2, getutcdate())
```

As you can see, I am unsure how to tell SQL the `VolumeID` that has just been inserted, which is `2`.

Below is the trigger that I wrote:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LoanStatusUpdate_OnLoaning
AFTER INSERT
ON LOAN
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VOLUME_VOLUME_STATUS (VolumeID, StatusID, DateCreated) 
    VALUES (>>previouslyInsertedVolumeID<<, 2, getutcdate())
END
```

Therefore, what should be passed as the value for the `VolumeID` column so that the parameter is the one from the `INSERT` prior to the trigger being activated?

Figured some errors in the previous trigger. Here's the one with fixed syntax errors:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LoanStatusUpdate_OnLoaning
ON LOAN
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO VOLUME_VOLUME_STATUS (VolumeID, StatusID, DateCreated) 
    VALUES (New.VolumeID, 2, getutcdate())
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to use `inserted`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LoanStatusUpdate_OnLoaning ON LOAN AFTER INSERT
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VOLUME_VOLUME_STATUS (VolumeID, StatusID, DateCreated) 
        SELECT i.VolumeId, 2, getutcdate()
        FROM inserted i;
END;
```

You can also pull the `StatusId` from `inserted` as well.  And `DateCreated` could be set as a default value in `VOLUME_VOLUME_STATUS`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, in my first example, I provided an errononous syntax and while your answer is very useful, it gives me this error: `Incorrect syntax near 'AFTER'.`

Comment: I will try to adapt it to the SQL Server syntax, nonetheless,!

Comment: @Questieme . . . I just copied that part of the code, because it didn't seem relevant.  The `ON` precedes the `AFTER`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will accept the answer once the cooldown expires.